# Regex - String matching

Tags: regex

I have an input like:

```
</name> rahul is nice guy <version=name> previous name is manoj </version> and cool </s>
```

I am using a regex to

```
re.search(r'(</name>([a-z0-9]+)(?!<version>(.*?)</version>)([a-z0-9]+)</s>)', line, re.M|re.I)
```

My output should be:

```
rahul is nice guy and cool
```

It doesnt match the pattern, and I am trying to omit words in between the 'version' tags ,can someone tell me where I am going wrong??

Written in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern matches:

```
</name>([a-z0-9 ]+)<version=name>(.*?)</version>([ a-z0-9]+)</s>
```

Note the spaces, `[a-z0-9 ]`, and note the characters you forgot `=name`.
Of course you have to take the first match and the third match.

If it's python - to take the text but not the text inside the version name:

```
Matches = re.findall(r'</name>([a-z0-9 ]+)<version=name>(.*?)</version>([ a-z0-9]+)</s>', line, re.M|re.I)
FinalText = Matches[0] + Matches[2]
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my edit, you have to combine the first and the third match, I gave an example in python, seemed like that was the language you are using, next time please mention the language in the question. @user3747896

Answer (score 0):

Find matched group at index 1 using below regex:

```
<\/name>[^<](.*?)\s*<
```

Here is demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xX9uC0), [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1QIlgsYkvHl-LUvF) and [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/391g0)